# UIBarButtonItem bold non-standard font when selected/active

Tags: swift, ios8, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

I want to setup `UIBarButtonItem` so that it uses a different font throughout my app. I'm doing this using `appearance`, however I have hit an issue with how to display the font in **bold** when its selected. Here is what I want to do:

```
var barButtonItemApperance = UIBarButtonItem.appearance()
barButtonItemApperance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Apple SD Gothic Neo", size: 16)!], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
barButtonItemApperance.setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Apple SD Gothic Neo", size: 16)!], forState: UIControlState.Selected) // I want this to be in bold text
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? The font is definitely 100% available in bold.

Answer (score 0):

for making text bold, this is the general syntax:

```
customLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.0f]
```

But you can simply choose the bold version of the font **Apple SD Gothic Neo**, Below is the list:

---

- AppleSDGothicNeo-Thin
- AppleSDGothicNeo-Light
- AppleSDGothicNeo-Regular
- AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium
- AppleSDGothicNeo-SemiBold
- AppleSDGothicNeo-Bold
- AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium